# How to store 1:n self reference (dependencies) in relational database

Tags: database-design

What is a clean way to store items that reference multiple other items of the same type in a relational database?

Say I have a list of jar files and their dependencies:

```
package1 depends on package2,package3
package2 depends on package3
package2 depends on nothing
```

Now I could store that in a database as follows

```
CREATE TABLE packages (
   pid STRING NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   name STRING NOT NULL,
   dependencies INTEGER NOT NULL -- foreign key
)
CREATE TABLE dependencies (
   did STRING NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   dependent INTEGER NOT NULL, -- foreign key
   dependentOn ??? 
)
```

But that would not be normalized and changing one relationship means touching all of them. How could I do that better?

Comment: Is the `package2 depends on nothing` line meant to be package3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the specific question you asked, the usual way to model a 1:N dependency on a normalized relational database is to put the link on the N side. That would mean, in this case, adding a sort of "is depended on by" column on the package table (name it however it makes sense to you), and not making a second table.

However, and moving beyond the specific question to the problem you're trying to solve, I'd argue that dependencies are generally M:N relationships. Even in your example, `package3` appears twice in the dependency list<sup>1</sup>. Besides, you never know when you're going to make a `package4` which also depends on `package2`, which would force you to rewrite the database to support that (suddenly) M:N link. Thus, I would personally model it by having another table like

```
CREATE TABLE dependencies (
    dependent INTEGER NOT NULL, -- foreign key
    dependentOn INTEGER NOT NULL -- foreign key 
)
```

I think having a dependency ID as in your example is a bit superfluous in this case.

---

<sup>1</sup> Assuming you mean `package1` depends on `package3` by means of `package2`, that would indeed be a 1:N relationship, but in that case you wouldn't establish a direct link between `package1` and `package3` in the database.

Comment: Darn, I was writing a very similar answer but you went one step farther with it by dumping the dependency id entirely, which I should've thought of too. +1

Comment: @Ixrec I saw it well explained in another answer earlier (not sure if here or at StackOverflow): 1:N relationships are best thought of as optimizations of M:N relationships. And unless you're really, really sure that there's no way the 1:N will turn into more, you run smack into the old adage about premature optimization.